# How fast does Corruption/Crimson spread?

Tags: terraria

So I was wandering the surface looking for easy caves to explore and BAM, Crimson biome.

Now that I've discovered it, I'm a little worried about the area immediately to the left of it, since there are some nice caves I was planning to explore later on.

I haven't defeated Eye of Cthulhu yet, so I don't yet have the sunflowers to stop the spread of Crimson.

How much time (In-game and real time) do I have to stop the Crimson from spreading? How fast will it spread across a normal biome?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It'll spread for the most part about 3-6 blocks per day depending on your biome and blocks. And to be honest after Hardmode is initiated you don't NEED the crimson really. So go buy the clentaminator and just ... well, get rid of it. If you ever need more just buy red solution from Steampunker during blood moon and make some :) Solves the pesky hardmode spred problem. Quite often a good idea is to make a world that is 100% crimson/corruption and have my home world corruption/crimson free! If you REALLY aren't capable of killing the WoF in a day or so (irl) then a good idea is to make a 3 block wide helevator on either side of corruption/crimson so that it can't spread! Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Itll spread about 3-6 blocks per day. The blocks it spreads on are: Grass Stone Mud Sand. a way to stop the spread is to put a 3 block thick wood wall around the whole corruption biome than put a door on the top. The dryad also sells purification powder which gets rid of corruption and crimson.

Comment: Does it spread through stone pre-hardmode? That's certainly new to 1.2 then. In 1.1 it only spread over grass pre-hardmode.

Comment: @Aperum it doesnt spread over stone pre-hardmode but it does spread over grass at an alarming rate so you should quarantine it with wood as quick as possible

Comment: Is that the speed at which it spreads before Hardmode, afterwards, or both? I'm actually most concerned about pre-hardmode corruption/crimson spread, since I have plenty of time to control when Hardmode initiates, but the Crimson is there right now.

Comment: Pre-hardmode, you only have to worry about grass and thorns.  Any non-dirt barrier should work.

Comment: @jw013 I know I accepted an answer already, and I've built a barrier as well but...I'm wondering now how far down my barrier needs to go.  I made it 5+ blocks wide, but I'm not sure how far down it neeeds to be (I made it roughly 6 blocks down).

Comment: @Zibbobz It's not as simple as up or down - if there are cave networks between the biomes you have to worry about that too.  Pay attention to what I said: pre-hardmode, it's just *grass* and *thorns*.  Grass will not spread through solid blocks, and thorns need air to grow.  That's all you need to know.  Go find where you have corrupt grass exposed to air and put up a barrier.  A single sunflower will work most of the time until you get to hardmode.

Comment: Sounds like I might need to fill in the "doorway" I built into my gate then...possibly, if thorns might spread into it...otherwise I think I'll probably be fine.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

@zibbobz Just depends, if your corruption is in the desert or snow biome then, well... you need to make REALLY DEEP! Like 100 blocks maybe if it’s bad enough, if it is a forest then probably only about 6 blocks. Oh btw it’s 1.4 now so you don’t have to worry about corrupters spreading corruption anymore, because they don’t spread it! :)